# Particle Sampling - how to change the time

Tags: animation, particles

I have a question relating to particles, one that I couldn't find answer to on google.

How can I change the time at which a particle emitter samples the particle? In other words, if I have an animated particle, how can make the emitter emit the particle with it's animation running from different point other than default. (in normal situation - all particles just duplicate the same animation, regardless of their birth time)

If that helps - I seek option similiar to particle sampling in After Effects plugin - Trapcode Particular.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean how to get more frames, _between_ the frames you're already getting?

Comment: Imagine a group of flowers that open at the same time - that's default particle emitter setting, as all particles use sampling from the same moment in time. Now imagine flowers that open at the different moment in time - this is when particles sample source particle at different moments.

Comment: The post is somewhat solved by using differently animated particles with a "duplicate group" setting in particle emitter.